# How I can add elements to arrays retrieved using AngularFire?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using angularfire to retrieve data from firebase to feed aangular model array variable, all works fine with firebase & angular, but I don't know how to mix in the same array data from firebase and other data

```
var leaderboardRef = new Firebase("https://<firebase-path>");
var obj = $firebase(leaderboardRef);
$firebase(leaderboardRef).$bind($scope, 'scores');
```

For example

I have in firebase

```
[
  {name: 'Alice', score: 1000},
  {name: 'Bob', score: 2000}
]
```

So, if I implement the code above, I get exactly that on $scope.scores, what I want to get is a mix of elements from firebase AND from another source (for example, a json file)

```
var leaderboardRef = new Firebase("https://<firebase-path>");
var obj = $firebase(leaderboardRef);
$firebase(leaderboardRef).$bind($scope, 'scores');
// ... mix the data ... I don't know how
... {name: 'Carl', score: 3000} ...
```

Then what I want to get from this is:

```
[
  {name: 'Alice', score: 1000},
  {name: 'Bob', score: 2000},
  {name: 'Carl', score: 3000}
]
```

On $scope.scores

How I can mix the data of different services ?

Comment: can use [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 0):

You can add some data with the .push-function. For this you have to had access to the array. 
Search the internet for "javascript array push".

Example:

```
var a = []
a.push({a:1, b:2})
a.push({a:3, b:4})
console.log(a)
```

Comment: That is not an answer, please read the question again, it is not as simply as it seems, I am talking here about dynamic arrays feed by angular services